# Container onclick toggle between video element and text

Tags: jquery, css, video, toggle

I'm trying to create a class of div that when clicked, toggles between a video element that plays on hover, or a paragraph of text. Each one fills the inside of the container. The container should ideally flex with the browser window too.

```css
.box {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  border: dotted red;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  font-size: 2vw;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text>video {
  display: none;
}

.vid>text {
  position: absolute;
  opacity 0;
}

.vid>video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
        $("a").toggleClass("vid, text");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <a class="vid">
      <video autoplay muted><source src=assets/IMG_1353.MOV></video>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut suscipit magna, ac imperdiet diam. Pellentesque quis tellus et nisi luctus efficitur vitae in quam. In maximus aliquam dui sed vulputate. Duis sed urna in ipsum efficitur ultricies
        at sit amet ligula. Curabitur feugiat placerat velit a mollis. Phasellus ac mollis metus. Pellentesque condimentum urna eu ex vulputate semper. Fusce pulvinar, dui id convallis aliquam, elit lectus convallis tellus, sit amet semper lectus nisl
        vehicula enim. Curabitur est augue, pharetra non orci vitae, rutrum fermentum nunc. Curabitur a tempor elit, et fermentum erat. Etiam iaculis nulla vitae nisl pretium venenatis. Maecenas convallis placerat vestibulum. Duis vel interdum quam. Nunc
        ultricies elit ut dolor bibendum commodo. Nam mollis diam tellus, non imperdiet purus facilisis in.Aliquam vitae malesuada lacus, a eleifend justo. Mauris in condimentum nisi, vel pulvinar magna. Suspendisse nibh augue, scelerisque in suscipit
        id, interdum sed arcu. Cras semper varius ante. Integer mollis, tellus quis interdum porttitor, ipsum dui venenatis elit, ut luctus magna est eu ex. Praesent pretium purus nisi. Duis pharetra aliquet diam, sed tincidunt enim. Mauris nunc sapien,
        mattis sed tincidunt sed, bibendum id eros. Pellentesque velit arcu, viverra id ipsum vel, venenatis hendrerit purus. Ut auctor quis ligula non laoreet. Proin id porta sapien. Nunc et felis id augue ultricies sollicitudin eget pellentesque justo.
        Etiam magna neque, tincidunt a quam in, varius suscipit quam. Cras tincidunt feugiat ex sit amet interdum. Aliquam sagittis turpis eu pulvinar convallis. Donec imperdiet euismod nisl et faucibus.</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's a couple of bad things in your code snippet: 1) You shouldn't really be changing the click behaviour of an anchor tag. Maybe use a simple `<button>` for that. And also, your CSS should be at least inside a `<style>` tag.

Comment: hi @MartinJoiner, thanks for the comment! I think <button> will work much better. Apologies, my css is in a css file usually, this was from not knowing how stack overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you're passing to toggleClass method weren't properly separated.

This should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("a").toggleClass("vid", "text");
    });
});
```

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("a").toggleClass("vid, text");
    });
});
```